# How can I traverse back and add an object into an object list that I created in a previous runs of my recursive method?

Tags: java, list, object

> All this program is trying to achieve is listing files as well as folders in a correct fashion , so that folders are assigned their own lists of objects.Files are excluded from having a list of objects as they won't contain any files or folders inside of themselves.
>    My main concern here is that the objects that are being recursively read and written in the data.class, that the objects from the main , or rather "root", are not being all joined into one , consecutive list of objects at the end. Please help.

```
package bstTest2;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "G:/a";
        File f = new File(filename);        

        data d= new data();
        d.explore(f);
    }
}

package bstTest2;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node{ 
    private String filename;
    private long size;
    private List<Node> prevList;
    private List<Node> curList;
    private List<Node> chList;//child list of the current node - could be null if the node is a file 
    private List<Node> root;

    Node(String fn, long s,List<Node> previousList, List<Node> currentList,List<Node> childList){
        filename = fn;
        size = s;
        setPrevList(previousList);
        setCurList(currentList);
        setChList(childList);
    } 

    public Node() {
        initList();
    }

    public void initList(){
        curList = new LinkedList<Node>();
        setRoot(curList);
    }

    public void createNode(File file){
        curList.add(new Node(file.getName(),file.length(),null,curList,null));
    }


    public void createNodeList(File file){
        curList.add(new Node(file.getName(),file.length(),
            prevList,
        setCurList(chList), setChList(setCurList(new LinkedList<Node>()))));
    } 


    public List<Node> getChList() {
        return chList;
    }

    public List<Node> setChList(List<Node> chList) {
        this.chList = chList;
        return chList;
    }

    public List<Node> getCurList() {
        return curList;
    }

    public List<Node> setCurList(List<Node> curList) {
        this.curList = curList;
        return curList;
    }

    public List<Node> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(List<Node> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public List<Node> getPrevList() {
        return prevList;
    }

    public void setPrevList(List<Node> prevList) {
        this.prevList = prevList;
    }
}

package bstTest2;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
public class data {

    private Node node = new Node();
    private File f[];  

    public void explore(File dir){
        f=dir.listFiles();
        if(f!=null){
            for(File file:f){
                if(!file.isDirectory()){    


                        //System.out.println("BFIL"+node.getCurList());
                        System.out.println("FILE: "+file.getName()+" "+file.length() +":");

                        node.createNode(file);

                        System.out.println(node.getCurList().size()+" AFIL"+node.getCurList());
                }else{


                        //System.out.println("BFOL"+node.getCurList());

                        System.out.println("FOLDER: "+file.getName()+" "+file.length() +":");

                        node.createNodeList(file);

                        System.out.println(node.getCurList().size() +" AFOL"+node.getCurList() );

                        explore(file);
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the list of files that are contained within a directory. Doing that will allow you to add that list of files to the directory node.

To do this you would change your `expore(File dir)` method to return the list of nodes within the directory and you would update your `explore(file);` call to add that list to the directory node.

```
public List<Node> explore(File directory) {
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for (File current : directory.listFiles()) {
        Node node = toNode(current);
        // do the real work here

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            node.setChildren(explore(file));
        }

        result.add(node);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The alternative is to pass the directory node to the `explore(File dir)` method and update it within that method. You can then add each contained file or directory node to that parent node.

```
public void explore(File directory, Node parent) {
    for (File current : directory.listFiles()) {
        Node node = toNode(current);
        // do the real work here

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            explore(file, node);
        }

        parent.add(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to implement that with code? I can't really grasp on what do you mean.

Comment: I will give you some sample code. The code you have provided is rather verbose to show what I am talking about clearly.

Comment: Thanks , and sorry for that I've only been programming in java for around 3 years.

Comment: It's fine. For a fuller explanation of this approach you should look up the Visitor Pattern.